# Why does the Greek use different words for "like" in Revelation 13:11?

Tags: greek, revelation, grammar, apocalyptic

Westcott & Hort 1881

> Καὶ εἶδον ἄλλο θηρίον ἀναβαῖνον ἐκ τῆς γῆς, καὶ εἶχεν κέρατα δύο ***ὅμοια*** ἀρνίῳ, καὶ ἐλάλει ***ὡς*** δράκων.

Revelation 13:11-18 English Standard Version (ESV)
The Second Beast

> 11 Then I saw another beast rising out of the earth. It had two horns ***like*** a lamb and it spoke ***like*** a dragon.

In the above text why does the Greek employ different words for "like"?

Comment: It looks like natural variation in wording to me. The same variation happens in Daniel 7 between כְ and דָּמְיָה לְ (Aramaic) or ὡσεὶ and ὁμοίωσιν (Greek)

Comment: Young's Literal has 'two horns like a lamb, speaking as a dragon'.One is a likeness of appearance; the other is a similarity of activity.

Comment: @NigelJ Please don't use the comment section for mini answers. They should be reserved for requests for clarification or suggestions for improvements. The ideal response to a comment should be an edit to update the post. Posting answer content in comments messes up the system because the sorting, editing, and other functions are not available as they should be on answers.

Comment: Noted and understood. That was an old habit, back in early last year. I shall turn the above comment into a full answer as soon as I have time. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

ὅμοιος, οία, οιον [Strong 3664](https://biblehub.com/greek/3664.htm) is given by Thayer as 'resembling' 'like' or 'equivalent to'.

ὡς [Strong 5613](https://biblehub.com/greek/5613.htm) is given by Thayer as 'in the same manner' 'after the same fashion'.

It is a subtle difference but I think the meanings are made clear by both the Englishman's Greek New Testament interlinear translation and by Young's Literal translation.

> ... horns, two, like to a lamb and spoke as a dragon. [EGNT]
>
> ... and it had two horns, like a lamb, and it was speaking as a dragon. [YLT]

The appearance was similar to a lamb, due to the possession of horns.
But the speech was 'as' a dragon.

Its appearance was 'like' one thing, but its activity was 'as' another thing.